# table notes in memoir

Tags: footnotes, memoir, tables

How do I have footnotes in a table while using memoir?

I tried ctable, but I get the following errors:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2008/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty:4022: No room for a new \dimen .
/usr/local/texlive/2008/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty:4022: leading text: \newdimen\Field@Width
/usr/local/texlive/2008/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty:4023: No room for a new \dimen .
/usr/local/texlive/2008/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty:4023: leading text: \newdimen\Fld@charsize
/usr/local/texlive/2008/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.tex:137: No room for a new \dimen .
/usr/local/texlive/2008/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.tex:137: leading text: ... \csname newdimen\endcsname \scratchdimen
/usr/local/texlive/2008/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.tex:1253: No room for a new \dimen .
/usr/local/texlive/2008/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.tex:1253: leading text: \newdimen\MPscratchDim
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [threeparttable](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/threeparttable.html) package is compatible with memoir.

Comment: is threeparttable more highly recommended than ctable?

Comment: It's a matter of taste. Personally, I don't like the way ctable deviates from standard LaTeX syntax (by using a command instead of an environment to create floats).

Note that I wrongly assumed ctable was incompatible with memoir.

Answer (score 5):

Errors with this messages may be resolved using `etex`:

```
\usepackage{etex}
```

The error message means that the dimen register set is full. etex allows to use e-TeX’s extended register sets. See the TeX FAQ: [No room for a new ‘thing’](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-noroom).

Comment: I get elatex not found?

Comment: That must be related to your editor. `elatex` is obsolete and not included in newer distributions since the e-TeX extensions have been merged with the "normal" LaTeX.