# What are benefits of e-TeX for LaTeX users?

Tags: packages, e-tex

The `etex` package provides an interface to e-TeX features. What advantages does it offer to LaTeX users?

Are there any possible disadvantages like incompatibility to any other package or can I just use it without worries?

Comment: Your question title says 'e-TeX' (the extended engine), but the body says '`etex`' (the LaTeX package). I'm a bit confused: do you mean the extensions or just the package.

Comment: Mainly the difference I can achieve by using the etex package - but additional e-TeX infos are very welcome.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

e-TeX provides lots of additional features for package writers such as an increased number of registers. The thing I find most useful is its extended tracing ability which I usually access through the `trace` package. In particular, tracing commands and tracing assignments are extremely helpful when trying to diagnose a problem.

e-TeX also provides a `\middle` delimiter that works like `\left` and `\right` which can be helpful.

```
\[\left\{\sum_{i=0}^n a_i\ \middle|\ a_0<a_1<\dotsb<a_n\right\}\]
```

Edit: While writing an answer to another question, I just remembered two pretty useful extensions in e-TeX. The first is `\unless` which lets you negate the arms of an `\if`. It's especially useful in loops where you want to loop unless some condition is true. Reading files was my example.

```
\loop\unless\ifeof\file
    \readline\file to\foo
    % Do something with \foo
\repeat
```

This also shows the second of the two extensions: `\readline`. It acts exactly like `\read` except that all of the characters are given category code other or space. It's very handy for reading in text that contains characters like `$`, `%`, `^`, `&`, `_`, or `\`. For example, here's a cheater's quine.

```
\newread\file
\openin\file\jobname
\endlinechar-1
\tt
\loop\unless\ifeof\file
\readline\file to\foo
\noindent\foo\endgraf
\repeat
\bye
```

There are other category changing commands like `\scantokens` and `\detokenize`, but I've never used either.

Comment: So, `\middle` comes from e-Tex. Good to know, I've seen people writing it would come from amsmath. I checked it, there's no such definition in the ams files. Just tried `\middle`: it works in a minimal document without any package, not even `\usepackage{etex}` is necessary.

Comment: One thing about eTeX is there seems no good manual for it. Am I right?

Comment: @Leo: The e-tex manual is at http://www.tug.org/texmf-dist/doc/etex/base/etex_man.pdf

Comment: @Leo: With TL 2009 I got the manual (20 pages) by `texdoc etex`.

Comment: For the user, I think the extra registers available are the most obvious feature. Of course, the programming stuff lets you do clever things, but I guess that most users only see this in the end results. A good example would be `biblatex`.

Comment: These are all features of the e-tex engine, not the `etex.sty` package.

Comment: From reading `etex.sty`, it seems like access to more registers are when using `\newX` come from it. In addition, `etex` redefines `\tracingall` if you care to use that interface. I prefer using the `trace` package.

Comment: @Lev Bishop: The registers are from the engine, but you need to load the `etex` *package* to be able to use them from LaTeX. Loading `etex` as the very first package is often a good choice in large documents, since it prevents LaTeX from running out of registers when lots of packages are loaded.

Comment: You've never used `\detokenize`! It's probably my second-favourite e-TeX primitive [I'd say `\unexpanded` is my favourite :-)].

Comment: I've never used either. How does `\unexpanded` differ from sticking the tokens in a token register and then using `\the` on it?

Comment: @TH.: `\unexpanded` is expandable.

Answer (score 25):

Looking at the e-TeX extensions in general, I'd highlight two points that have not been mentioned by others. First, e-TeX provides primitives for carrying out calculations when assigning integers, dimensions, *etc*. For example,

```
\newcount\mycount
\mycount\numexpr 1 + 2 * 3\relax
\showthe\mycount
```

will give `7`. Now, you can do something similar with the `calc` package, but only for LaTeX-managed variables. I find the e-TeX primitives particularly handy with [`Tikz`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf), as it uses TeX registers directly and so does not work with the `calc` package. e-TeX means that things like

```
\tikzset{ key-name = \dimexpr 3 * \SomeDimension\relax }
```

work nicely.

Secondly, and more 'conceptually', LaTeX users get the benefit from packages that use e-TeX primitives for the code; one I'd point to is [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex). As a programmer, the e-TeX extensions make many things much easier, and also allow programming ideas that simply don't work with TeX82 (*i.e.* TeX written by Knuth). The direct influence of e-TeX may not show up to users, but the availability of packages certainly does.

Comment: Write: This is sort of tangential, but why rename the registers yet again? LaTeX already changes some names, for example skips are called lengths, counts were changed to counter—but with the bizarre addition of `c@`. Why rename them to ints now?

Comment: They used to be called "cnt" in latex3 but it was long ago decided that name was a little awkward and perhaps rude. Besides, what other language *doesn't* call them "int"?

Answer (score 20):

It should be pointed out that already a number years ago the LaTeX Project officially announced that LaTeX is expected to be run on an e-TeX-based enabled engines. In other words: all functionality available in e-TeX is supposed to be available for the LaTeX kernel and any add-on packages.

So far, the LaTeX Project Team hasn't made changes to the "kernel" that would not run without e-TeX, but there are packages including some maintained by the team that do require this functionality. This is in particular true for all work on LaTeX3, e.g., the `expl3` based packages.

The `etex.sty` package is the core package for LaTeX2e enabling those e-TeX extensions that are not automatically available when using the right formatter. It is based on Peter Breitenlohner's package `etex.src`.

Answer (score 18):

Now I found the [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package. It's a toolbox of programming facilities providing LaTeX frontends to some new e-TeX primitives and further features.

It supports

- Definition of "robust" commands: `\newrobustcmd`, `\renewrobustcmd` etc.
- Patching existing commands to be robust: `\robustify`
- Protecting entire chunks of code by `\protecting`
- Defining counters and lengths with arithmetic expressions (`\defcounter`, `\deflength`)
- Using hooks similar to `\AtBeginDocument` but in different variants: `\AfterPreamble`, `\AtEndPreamble`, `\AfterEndPreamble` and `\AfterEndDocument`
- Many shorthands for macro definitions (corresponding to `\def`, `\gdef`, `\edef`, `\let` etc. but with control sequences as first argument and robust)
- Undefining macros
- Arithmetic definitions (similar to `\def`, `\edef` etc. but with integer expressions)
- Expansion control (useful in `\edef` and the like) by `\expandonce`
- Hook management: appending and prepending to hooks
- Patching of existing commands: extracts the text of a command, does search&replace in the code, and reassembles it - nice for workarounds
- Appending and prepending to commands
- Control sequence tests (if defined, if empty, equality)
- String tests (equality, empty or blank)
- Artihmetic tests
- Two different interfaces to boolean switches
- List processing

If some of the features seem to be interesting for you, there's documentation available: `texdoc etoolbox` at the command prompt or the [package documentation](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/etoolbox/etoolbox.pdf) on CTAN, a reference manual with 30 pages.

The package [`etextools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etextools) bases on `etoolbox` and provides many further macros. You can access its documentation also by `texdoc` and [on CTAN](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/etextools/etextools.pdf).

Comment: Rather more on the 'programmers' side than the 'users' side :-) I'd point out that there is quite a bit of overlap with ideas in `expl3` (although the two approaches have arrived that way independently).

Comment: I should also note that a bit of `etoolbox` is things that don't depend on e-TeX but simply things that should be in LaTeX that are not

Comment: True, the manual says it further contains 'some generic tools which are not related to e-TeX but match the profile of this package'.

Answer (score 14):

`etex.sty` seems aim to be to LaTeX as `etex.src` is to plain TeX. It seems to be useful for giving nice names to e-TeX (the engine)'s magic constants, so you can write `\hboxgrouptype` for 2, `\ligaturenode` for 7, and so on. It is loaded internally by quite a lot of packages.

Another feature it provides is transparently making the extended register pool available if the normal pool gets exhausted. It is recommended for the user to load it to help with 'no room for a new *thing*' errors, as in [this FAQ answer](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-noroom)

Comment: Yes, we've got such an error here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1680/table-notes-in-memoir.

Comment: The `etex` package is loaded by a number of other LaTeX packages which require e-TeX, for example `biblatex` and `expl3`. (I guess you could say that the availability of e-TeX depended package is a benefit to LaTeX users, as by using e-TeX the package authors have provided things which are hard to do otherwise.)

Comment: @Joseph: you are right. I had a bug in my `grep` commandline, so I fixed my answer.

Comment: I was going on the rather more basic 'I know this as I've read/written the code'!

Comment: @Joseph: On the other hand, packages requiring e-TeX cannot be used with distributions which do not support e-TeX. :-(

Comment: @Stephen. e-TeX was finalised in _1999_. While some commercial publishing systems based on TeX still don't use the extensions as standard, any up-to-date TeX system will have them.

Comment: @Joseph: Yes, it's one of those commercial publishing systems I had in mind.

Comment: @Stephen: I'm aware of these, but there is a _reason_ for the e-TeX extensions. If you don't support them, then you also tend to have an ancient set of packages, and there is a limit to how far it is possible to 'code around' such a situation. (You can argue it's stable, but then in such an environment you should not be looking to use new material, just the methods it provides.)

Comment: @Stephen since about 2004 LaTeX officially requires e-TeX as an underlying processor (or rather a processor that supports all of the e-TeX extensions). As a project we make this switch finally when for already a number of years all major distributions where based on eTeX or at least has the processor on board.

Answer (score 8):

If one wants to implement some sort of multiline widow/orphan control (e.g. "For the first paragraph following a sectional heading, page breaks are allowed only after the third and following lines"), standard (La)TeX only offers approximate solutions (mostly involving the [`needspace`](http://ctan.org/pkg/needspace) package). With e-TeX, exact solutions are possible using the `\widowpenalties` and `\clubpenalties` macros. See [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2347/avoiding-page-breaks-shortly-after-section-subsection-headings/2358#2358) answer for an example.

Joseph Wright has already mentioned `biblatex` as a "user-relevant" package which uses e-TeX primitives; another one is [`marginnote`](http://ctan.org/pkg/marginnote) which (contrary to standard LaTeX's `\marginpar` command) allows margin notes for floats and footnotes.