# Avoiding page breaks shortly after section/subsection headings

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking, e-tex, sections-paragraphs

By default, LaTeX allows a page break after the first two lines of paragraphs following section/subsection headings. How can I enlarge this minimum to, say, three lines or 10 percent of the value of `\textheight`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There may be a generalisable mechanism: Using e-TeX and its `\clubpenalties` command. In the following example, patching `\@afterheading` seems to do the trick.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etex}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@afterheading}%
    {\clubpenalty \@M}{\clubpenalties 3 \@M \@M 0}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@afterheading}%
    {\clubpenalty \@clubpenalty}{\clubpenalties 2 \@clubpenalty 0}{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{blindtext}

\textheight 480pt

\begin{document}

\section{bla}

\blindtext[3]

\section{blubb}

\blindtext

\clearpage

\section{foo}

\blindtext[3]

An extra line.

\section{bar}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

UPDATE: egreg has written a [detailed explanation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21983/how-to-avoid-page-breaks-inside-paragraphs/21985#21985) of `\widowpenalties` and `\clubpenalties`.

Comment: Neat. I didn't know \clubpenalties. One lives and learn.

Comment: That must be the first time I taught you something, Ulrike. ;-)

Note: I'm not sure about the workings of `\clubpenalties`, but I've edited my code example so that the third penalty value (which seems to affect the third and all following lines of a paragraph) is 0 instead of `\@clubpenalty` (which defaults to 150).

Comment: I don't think you need the third argument at all if you want to affect only the first 3 lines. But I have some doubts about your patch: Your setting affects now all following paragraphs. If you want to set the penalty only for the first, you must reset \clubpenalties with "\clubpenalties 0" in the "else"-part of \@afterheading.

Comment: If I replace `\clubpenalties 3 \@M \@M 0` with `\clubpenalties 2 \@M \@M`, no page break is allowed at all. But your're right about all following paragraphs being affected; I've edited my code example to solve this issue.

Comment: Oooh, I didn't know about `\clubpenalties` either.  Nor did I know about the `etex` documentation or `etoolbox`.  That's a _good_ value answer!

Answer (score 20):

I solved this with the *needspace* and *titlesec* packages, as in:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{needspace}
...
\titleformat{\section}
{\needspace{1in}\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
```

Hardcoding 1in is crude -- should probably be a multiple of line height.
At any rate, this works great in my documents without the need for hand tuning each section.

Comment: @srking: Thanks, but Ulrike Fischer and Lev Bishop already mentioned `needspace` in their answers.

Comment: @lockstep - Sure, but I just found combining needspace with titlesec capability to be particularly convenient.  Cheers.

Comment: @lockstep: The advantage of srking's solution is obviouly that one doesn't need to manually put `\Needspace` (and that it works without `\patchcmd` trickery), so +1 from me.

Comment: @Hendrik: You're right -- +1, and +1 for @srking's answer.

Comment: @lockstep: By the way, you also got +1 from me for `\clubpenalties`.

Comment: Actually, titlesec provides a feature very similar to needspace with `\bottomtitlespace`.

Comment: The `nobottomtitles` titlesec package option solves this problem.

Answer (score 13):

You could use needspace. With a bit calculations and tests it shouldn't be too difficult to find sensible values:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,needspace}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1] \vspace{27\baselineskip}

\Needspace{7\baselineskip}
\section{Blubb}
\lipsum[1]

\newpage
\lipsum[1] \vspace{28\baselineskip}

\Needspace{7\baselineskip}
\section{Blabb}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
\patchcmd{\@afterheading}%
    {\clubpenalty \@M}{\clubpenalties 3 \@M \@M 0}{}{}
```

`\patchcmd` works for all cleanable parameterless macros, but it is meant for cleanable parameterized macros. For parameterless macros, LaTeX `\g@addto@macro` does the job without the need for the `<success>` and `<failure>` parts and, of course, without the need for `etoolbox`.

Comment: Oops, I am very sorry, I got it wrong! \patchcmd searches and replaces!

Answer (score 4):

[`titlesec`](https://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) offers the option `nobottomtitles` to move titles close to the bottom to the next page. The starred variant is more accurate, see the manual. By default the threshold is `.2\textheight`.

```
\usepackage[nobottomtitles*]{titlesec}
\renewcommand{\bottomtitlespace}{.2\textheight} % default value
```

Comment: This is the only option that actually works.

Comment: it seems to work well, except i am losing the format of my sections.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried it myself, but perhaps you can use the [needspace](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/needspace) package for this. Be sure to heed [the FAQ warning](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-nopagebrk) about how this may confuse tex, even if you do succeed in preventing page breaks between the lines (eg, ending up with an overfull page leaving those lines jutting out of the bottom of the page).

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a generalisable mechanism.

Single last lines or single first lines of a paragraph, appearing at the beginning or the end of a page, are known as 'widows' and 'orphans/clubs' (I think they're that way round).  TeX has a mechanism for avoiding, or at least penalising, widows and orphans, but it's specialised for this case of keeping the first or last two lines together, and it can't be extended to three lines or more.

There may be a way of addressing this by doing scary output routine gymnastics, but that would be a *very* exotic thing to do.

Comment: This true for TeX90, but [wrong for eTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21983/how-to-avoid-page-breaks-inside-paragraphs/21985#21985) - which all modern engines provide.

Comment: Oooh, I didn't know about `\clubpenalties` -- ta!