# How to avoid heading orphan?

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking, widows-orphans

I want to get rid of pages ending with a heading title only. 
I want at least 2 text rows following the heading title to make a better look.

What is the exact value to be passed to `\Needspace*{}` to avoid this heading orphan?

Comment: By default, pages should not end with a heading in LaTeX. Show a minimal example as evidence to the contrary.

Comment: @xport: I think it was a bad idea to change your user name beyond recognition. On this site, people just got to know you under the name xport.

Comment: @xport: If one of the answers solved your problem, please consider accepting an answer so that your question moves off the "Unanswered" list.

Comment: @Hendrik: DONE.

Comment: @xport: Ah, your back. While you're here, can you please also rename yourself to "xport", please? Thanks!

Comment: @Hendrik: DONE!

Comment: This question is very much related to ["Avoiding page breaks shortly after section/subsection headings"](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2347/1235). Is it a duplicate, @lockstep?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The normal way to control orphans is to adjust the `\clubpenalty` variable.
Try to set it to a high value. See https://texfaq.org/FAQ-widows for more information.

If you want to use `\Needspace*{}` I would assume that `4\baselineskip` is reasonable for the heading title plus two text rows. I'm simply counting the bigger heading title line twice, therefore the factor 4. You could experiment with factors between 3 and 4. The exact amount is of course dependent on the kind of heading that follows.

Comment: I don't think that `\clubpenalty` is relevant here: It controls how much first lines of _paragraphs_ at the bottom of a page a discouraged. The present post is about single line headings.

Comment: Ok, another thing learnt.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is what you're looking for but you could always use `\begin{samepage}` and `\end{samepage}` to keep together the stuff that you don't want to be separated.

There should be a penalty counter though that omits this dreadful use of the samepage environment. Read [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2347/avoiding-page-breaks-shortly-after-section-subsection-headings) for more info on the how to discourage latex in breaking pages after your headings.

Add the following to your preamble and you should be fine:

```
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@afterheading}%
    {\clubpenalty \@M}{\clubpenalties 3 \@M \@M 0}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@afterheading}%
    {\clubpenalty \@clubpenalty}{\clubpenalties 2 \@clubpenalty 0}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! Note that you don't have to (and shouldn't) sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post.

Comment: haha ok. I'll try to keep that in mind.