# Less whitespace and no indent at the same time using enumerate

Tags: spacing, line-spacing

I would like to ask the following:

I would like to use the theorem environment in my latex code. I also have some definitions and examples and I would like to let these environments look the same. Therefore, I produced the code below.

My problem is now, that I would like to display examples without indent, but when I do it as I did in the code below, I get a huge vertical whitespace between the word "Examples" and the first example.

> > Is it possible to avoid the whitespace and at the same time to have no indent?

Thanks for the help!

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{paralist}
\newtheoremstyle{dotless}{}{}{}{}{\bfseries}{}{\newline}{}
\theoremstyle{dotless}
\newtheorem{Definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem*{Examples*}{Examples}

\begin{document}

\begin{Definition}
Here comes a definition.
\end{Definition}

\begin{Examples*}
\
\begin{enumerate}[1)]
  \item First example.
  \item Second example.
  \item Third example.
\end{enumerate}
\end{Examples*}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: some relevant information here: [Theorem starting with a list](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154854/579)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this? You can use

```
\leavevmode
\vspace{-\baselineskip}    %% adjust this
```

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}     %%% changed
\newtheoremstyle{dotless}{}{}{}{}{\bfseries}{}{\newline}{}
\theoremstyle{dotless}
\newtheorem{Definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem*{Examples*}{Examples}

\begin{document}

\begin{Definition}
Here comes a definition.
\end{Definition}

\begin{Examples*}
\leavevmode
\vspace{-\baselineskip}    %% adjust this
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*),leftmargin=*]  %% add <nosep> also if you like
  \item First example.
  \item Second example.
  \item Third example.
\end{enumerate}
\end{Examples*}

\end{document}
```

Or use a `minipage`. But if you have too many items, then page break won't be feasible.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newtheoremstyle{dotless}{}{}{}{}{\bfseries}{}{\newline}{}
\theoremstyle{dotless}
\newtheorem{Definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem*{Examples*}{Examples}

\begin{document}

\begin{Definition}
Here comes a definition.
\end{Definition}

\begin{Examples*}

\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\par
\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}     %% adjust this
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*),leftmargin=*]  %% add <nosep> also if you like
  \item First example.
  \item Second example.
  \item Third example.
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}
\end{Examples*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can add `nosep` if you want to reduce the spaces further.

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*),leftmargin=*,nosep]
```

[image]

All these options are possible, if you use `enumitem` instead of `paralist` package.