# How to attach section-title to corresponding text?

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking

My title (`\chapter`, `\section` etc.) should always be attached to the corresponding, followed text. 
It happens that the title is squeezed into the last line of a page and the corresponding text on the next page, whereas it would be preferable when the title would always stay with at least 5 lines of the following text on one page.

Every hint is welcomed!

Comment: We need some more details of your document.  However, http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14554/15925 might be a help.

Comment: Thanks for the link! Yes a similar problem is described. I am using document class article and TexStudio. Is it generally possible to get an automatic page break if header stays alone on one page in the preamble?

Comment: Generally `article` will do its best to avoid isolated headers.  Ignore this problem until your document is essentially complete and then try adding some extra vertical space or a `\clearpage` before remaining offending headers.

Comment: You can use `titlesec` with option `nobottomtitles` and redefine the formatting/spacing of your `\chapter-\section-&c.` commands.