# adding Devanagari numerals in `verse' environment

Tags: xetex, indic, verse, devanagari

[Having the verses numbered](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/194414/231903)

In the above link, @joharr explains about how we can get the verses numbered within the `verse` environment.

**My Question:** How can we get Devanagari numbers (instead of Roman numbers) at the end of every 4 lines?

Comment: You can use the technique here [How to get devanagari numerals in latex or xetex](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/70414) to format the `poemline` counter that the `verse` package uses to number lines.

Comment: Please consider accepting the provided answer if it solved the question that you have asked.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `polyglossia`. The following example uses `marathi` language with Shobhika font. You can do something similar for Hindi too. This needs XeLaTeX.

```
% !TeX-program xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url,verse}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{marathi}
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari,Mapping=devanagarinumerals]{Shobhika}

\begin{document}
\begin{verse}[13em]
\poemlines{4}
\begin{altverse}
त्या व्याकुळ संध्यासमयी\\
  शब्दांचा जीव वितळतो\\
डोळ्यांत कुणाच्या क्षितिजे\\
  मी अपुले हात उजळतो\\[1ex]

तू आठवणीतुन माझ्या\\
  कधि रंगित वाट पसरशी,\\
अंधार-व्रताची समई\\
  कधि असते माझ्यापाशी\\[1ex]

पदराला बांधुन स्वप्ने\\
  तू एकट संध्यासमयी,\\
तुकयाच्या हातांमधला\\
  मी अभंग उचलुन घेई\\[1ex]

तू मला कुशीला घ्यावे\\
  अंधार हळू ढवळावा\\
संन्यस्त सुखाच्या काठी\\
  वळिवाचा पाऊस यावा\\[1ex]
\end{altverse}
\end{verse}
\end{document}
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Thank you @Niranjan.  I have two questions here. 1. In your example, it seems that the numbers are in multiples of four. But in my case, I need sequential numbering. How to do that? 2. Mine is a bilingual work, that is, Devanagari followed by Roman transliteration. How can I achieve numbering for both?

Comment: These are two different issues. I would suggest you to experiment a bit with this code. Read the manual of package [`polyglossia`](https://ctan.org/pkg/polyglossia) and post what problems do you get with examples. I am sure people will help you with the problems you face.