# Writing poems and tales

Tags: poetry

i am trying to write a book of *poems* and *short tales*. 
I do not pretend change font colour and things like that. Only poems and tales with a title. Maybe you know about some useful templates also.
As i am new in Latex just came here for some help.

Any answer with links and simple ideas will be good.

I do not know why there isn't *tag* for *tales*, it would be useful in this case.

Here is something similar to what i have tried. But it looks bad.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[headheight=18pt,a4paper, width=150mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm, bindingoffset=6mm, headsep=18pt]{geometry}
%aca utilizo la geometría de la hoja 
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
%interprete de idioma castellano
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} %relacionado al input
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\begin{document}
\title{\textbf{Caminata nocturna}}
\author{\vspace{-2cm} }
\date{\vspace{-2cm} }
\maketitle
Una vez mas frente a las estrellas. En la ciudad casi no se ven pero aquí, en el pueblo, Betelgeuse y Rigel resplandecen. Necesitaba observar, mirar la forma de cada constelación, mirar a las tres marías y al cazador Orión. Me asombra que otras culturas vieran otras formas en el cielo. Han dado un sentido distinto a su experiencia. Reflexiono, con certeza de modo erróneo, que el hombre (la psique) es un cúmulo de conceptos relativos.

Regreso a las estrellas y a los procesos físicos que ocurren en ellas, pienso.., pienso..Y poco a poco la mente va acallándose, hasta quedar muda. Largo tiempo suelo pasar, sin proponérmelo, bebiendo de ese olvido del mundo. 

Al volver, algo ha cambiado. Escucho con placer felino el silencio de la noche implacable.
Este silencio me llena de nada, de paz. 

\title{\textbf{El mito de creación olímpico}}
\author{\vspace{-2cm} }
\date{\vspace{-2cm} }
\maketitle
En el principio de todas las cosas Madre Tierra emergió de Caos y parió a su hijo Urano mientras dormía. Contemplándola cariñosamente, él derramó fértil lluvia sobre las quebradas, y ella parió pasto, flores, y árboles, con las bestias y aves respectivas.

Los primeros hijos de forma semi-humana fueron los gigantes Briareus, Gyges y Cottus, cada uno con cien brazos. Luego aparecieron tres salvajes Cíclopes de un ojo, constructores de paredes gigantes y herreros maestros, cuyos hijos enfrentaron a Odiseo en Sicilia. Se llamaban Brontes, Steropes, y Argos. Sus espíritus descansan en el volcán Aetna, desde que Apollo los asesinó para vengar la muerte de Asclepio.


\title{\textbf{Poema I}}
\author{\vspace{-2cm} }
\date{\vspace{-2cm} }
\maketitle

Canción

al alma

sol

\end{document}
```

Comment: Possibly related: [Typesetting poems](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94046/typesetting-poems)

Comment: [here](http://www.ntg.nl/maps/24/06.pdf) (PDF) is something which looks like a tutorial or short introduction to typesetting poetry.

Comment: The `memoir` class probably provides all you need. Try `texdoc memoir` chapter 14 Poetry.