# How to keep an environment with the last line of the previous environment?

Tags: page-breaking, environments

I quite often include attributed quotes in my documents, using something like:

```
\begin{quote}
    Now I am become Death, the destroyer of worlds.
    Also, I like bananas!

    I like bananas so much that my quotes about them run to \emph{multiple paragraphs}!
\end{quote}
\begin{flushright}Ronald MacDonald\end{flushright}
```

I would like to keep my `flushright` environment on the same page as the last line of my `quote` environment.

My idea was to write a new environment which would force a page break, if one is needed, to occur at or before the last line of my quote.

---

I can see from other questions (in particular [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21983/how-to-avoid-page-breaks-inside-paragraphs)) that I should use `widowpenalties`, but I'm having trouble working out how to apply a penalty *only* to the last line.

The examples on the other question seem to suggest that `\windowpenalties 3 x y 0` will apply a penalty of `x` to line -1, and `y` to all other lines.

In particular, it suggests

```
{\widowpenalties 4 10000 10000 -10000 0 \brokenpenalty 0 \par}
```

for breaking before the 3rd-last line of the paragraph.

---

However, I can't think how to write a `newenvironment` which will apply a penalty such that LaTeX breaks before the last line of a paragraph, but *only apply it to the last paragraph of my quote*.

Comment: Could you bring us a MWE complete? Personally I don't thin you need something so strange. The solution is for a case where those environments fall in different pages, but if the document is not complete yet I think it won't be useful, but if it does, then you can find another solution as you've mentioned. For me works fine this lines in the preamble:

`\raggedbottom`
`\clubpenalty=10000`
`\widowpenalty=10000`

You can play with the values for fit it to your document.

Comment: If the first environment introduces a vertical skip in anyway, they second will never be on the same line. Are you trying to quote a person? If so, have a look at package `csquotes`.

Answer (score 1):

You should not break the two parts into two environments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{mquote}{m}
 {\begin{quote}}
 {{\interlinepenalty 10000 \brokenpenalty 0 \par}% <--- change to \par, if you like
  \nopagebreak\makebox[\linewidth][r]{#1}\end{quote}}

\setlength\textheight{2cm}

\begin{document}
\noindent X\hrulefill X

\begin{mquote}{Ronald MacDonald}
Now I am become Death, the destroyer of worlds.
Also, I like bananas!

I like bananas so much that my quotes about them run to \emph{multiple paragraphs}!
\end{mquote}
\end{document}
```

With this code, the entire last paragraph will go in the next page together with the attribution; if you change

```
{\interlinepenalty 10000 \brokenpenalty 0 \par}
```

into `\par`, only the last line will move to the next page.

With

```
{\widowpenalties 3 10000 10000 0 \brokenpenalty 0 \par}
```

you'd ensure that the last *two* lines of the final paragraph will accompany the attribution on the next page.

Answer (score 0):

For quotes like that I usually include the attribution into the quote environment and make it "flush right" with an `\hfill`

```
\begin{quote}
    Now I am become Death, the destroyer of worlds.
    Also, I like bananas!

    I like bananas so much that my quotes about them run to \emph{multiple paragraphs}!\hfill Ronald MacDonald
\end{quote}
```

A MWE would help. The answer might depend on our format for "quote".

[image]