# prevent page break inside a sentence

Tags: page-breaking

I am asked to not break sentences so that they are on two pages. Is there a way to globally and automatically prevent sentences to be split into two pages? It should look like it would be a new paragraph. Of course, I could manually enter a blank line in front of each sentence that is split but this would be inconvenient as it has to be adapted each time new text is inserted before that sentence.

EDIT:
Example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% MWE only

\begin{document}
%\raggedbottom
%\interlinepenalty=10000

%This is the current text:

\lipsum[1-5]

Here is a new paragraph with a sentence that is split. This is the sentence which should be completely on the next page. Here is a new paragraph with a sentence that is split. Here is a new paragraph with a sentence that is split. Here is a new paragraph with a sentence that is split. Here is a new paragraph with a sentence that is split.

\lipsum[6-7]

\clearpage

%The layout which is asked for could be produced with the following commands. However, I would like to have it automated because there are a lot of these split sentences and in addition, I would have to always recheck all these sentences if I enter new text above.

\lipsum[1-5]

Here is a new paragraph with a sentence that is split. 

\noindent This is the sentence which should be completely on the next page. Here is a new paragraph with a sentence that is split. Here is a new paragraph with a sentence that is split. Here is a new paragraph with a sentence that is split. Here is a new paragraph with a sentence that is split.

\lipsum[6-7]

\clearpage

% or:

\lipsum[1-5]

Here is a new paragraph with a sentence that is split. \linebreak This is the sentence which should be completely on the next page. Here is a new paragraph with a sentence that is split. Here is a new paragraph with a sentence that is split. Here is a new paragraph with a sentence that is split. Here is a new paragraph with a sentence that is split.

\lipsum[6-7]

\clearpage

%or

\lipsum[1-5]

Here is a new paragraph with a sentence that is split. \clearpage \noindent This is the sentence which should be completely on the next page. Here is a new paragraph with a sentence that is split. Here is a new paragraph with a sentence that is split. Here is a new paragraph with a sentence that is split. Here is a new paragraph with a sentence that is split.

\lipsum[6-7]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I am not sure what you have to do. What do you mean by sentences on two pages? You can use \\ for a line break, and \newpage for a new page. Or do you mean to prevent a sentence being split across pages?

Comment: @FLonLon Thanks for your question. I mean to prevent a sentence being split across pages.

Comment: how to typeset Proust with such a constraint? if the whole page is part of a single sentence? if a sentence would be split across pages one has to go back to first word of sentence and insert a page break there, do I get this right?

Comment: @jfbu Yes, you would have to insert a page break before the first word of the sentence or begin a new paragraph which would hopefully be automatically placed at the next page. Luckily, my sentences are generally not so long.

Comment: @John_Kormylo For me, at this point, it is not important how it is achieved. Whatever is easier, reliable and more comfortable so that it can be adapted to the whole document automatically (without setting a command in front of each sentence that would otherwise be split).

Comment: The main problem is that LaTeX (TeX) formats paragraphs first, then splits them.  If I understand you correctly, you want to add a paragraph break at the end of the page.

Comment: Just to prevent confusion. When I write _paragraph_ here I do **not** mean the command `paragraph` but the thing you achieve by adding a blank line with the first line indented. Such a new paragraph would be one possible solution to prevent the line to be split. But I am open to other solutions.

Comment: The TeXbook says that TeX doesn't distinguish between abbr. and a sentence ending period, and I couldn't find anything in source2e to say that LaTeX is any different.

Answer (score 2):

This will prevent paragraphs from being split across pages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% MWE only

\begin{document}
\raggedbottom
\interlinepenalty=10000

\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This produces a lot of white space and I would prefer just to split paragraphs at the position of a page break. Also, this produced text outside of the page margins if the paragraphs were too long. Is there a possibility to automatically insert a new paragraph (i.e. split the paragraph) at the position of the page break.

Comment: your requirements are so specific, you HAVE to provide us with some of the code you are using. Johns answer is a valid answer to your [broad] question. Alternatively, check : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21983/how-to-avoid-page-breaks-inside-paragraphs

Comment: @FLoanLon I have updated the question and entered an example.

Comment: It occurred to me that adding an equation will split a sentence into 2 or more paragraphs.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean with an equation? Do you mean a mathematical expression? Probably, I still would have to add the equation manually to the page breaks, rigth?

Comment: I mean `\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}` or `\[ ... \]` or even `$$ ... $$`.  There is no penalty for breaking a page between paragraphs, so you cannot stop it short of putting the entire thing into a box (e.g. \parbox).

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thanks for clarification and help! I would need a penalty of breaking a sentence. I am fine with breaking a paragraph as long as the "breakpoint" is the ending of a sentence ".".

Comment: What I am saying is that LaTeX doesn't know what a sentence is.  It only knows paragraphs and lines of text,  You would first have to tell LaTeX where each sentence ends, which does not fit the "automatic" requirement.