# How can I control the minimum number of lines in last page?

Tags: lastpage

How can I control the minimum number of lines(5 lines) in last page?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Hello, here is some text without a meaning.  This text should show what 
a printed text will look like at this place.  If you read this text, 
you will get no information.  Really?  Is there no information?  Is there 
a difference between this text and some nonsense like not at all!  A 
blind text like this gives you information about the selected font, how 
the letters are written and an impression of the look.  This text should
contain all letters of the alphabet and it should be written in of the
original language.There is no need for special content, but the length of
words should match the language.

Hello, here is some text without a meaning.  This text should show what 
a printed text will look like at this place.  If you read this text, 
you will get no information.  Really?  Is there no information?  Is there 
a difference between this text and some nonsense like not at all!  A 
blind text like this gives you information about the selected font, how 
the letters are written and an impression of the look.  This text should
contain all letters of the alphabet and it should be written in of the
original language.There is no need for special content, but the length of
words should match the language.

Hello, here is some text without a meaning.  This text should show what 
a printed text will look like at this place.  If you read this text, 
you will get no information.  Really?  Is there no information?  Is there 
a difference between this text and some nonsense like not at all!  A 
blind text like this gives you information about the selected font, how 
the letters are written and an impression of the look.  This text should
contain all letters of the alphabet and it should be written in of the
original language.There is no need for special content, but the length of
words should match the language.

Hello, here is some text without a meaning.  This text should show what 
a printed text will look like at this place.  If you read this text, 
you will get no information.  Really?  Is there no information?  Is there 
a difference between this text and some nonsense like not at all!  A 
blind text like this gives you information about the selected font, how 
the letters are written and an impression of the look.  This text should
contain all letters of the alphabet and it should be written in of the
original language.There is no need for special content, but the length of
words should match the language.

Hello, here is some text without a meaning.  This text should show what 
a printed text will look like at this place.  If you read this text, 
you will get no information.  Really?  Is there no information?  Is there 
a difference between this text and some nonsense like not at all!  A 
blind text like this gives you information about the selected font, how 
the letters are written and an impression of the look.  This text should
contain all letters of the alphabet and it should be written in of the
original language.There is no need for special content, but the length of
words should match the language.

Hello, here is some text without a meaning.  This text should show what 
a printed text will look like at this place.  If you read this text, 
you will get no information.  Really?  Is there no information?  Is there 
a difference between this text and some nonsense like not at all!  A 
blind text like this gives you information about the selected font, how 
the letters are written and an impression of the look.  This text should
contain all letters of the alphabet and it should be written in of the
original language.There is no need for special content, but the length of
words should match the language.

\end{document}
```

Comment: you can use `\widowpenalties`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21985/2388 and the `nowidow` package.

Comment: Thanks Mr.Ulrike Fischer! Using \widowpenalties, I can get expected output. But i have another issue. If the file ends with bibliography, then \widowpenalties does not work in bibliography. Could you please give some solution.

Comment: I'm Mrs. Fischer, and if you have a new question, ask a new question with a suitable example.

Comment: I'm sorry Mrs. Fischer. I raised a new question. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/540156/how-can-i-control-automatically-the-minimum-number-of-lines5-lines-in-last-pag