# How can I control automatically the minimum number of lines(5 lines) in last page when it ends with reference list?

Tags: lastpage

How can I control automatically the minimum number of lines(5 lines) in last page when it ends with reference list?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Hello, here is some text without a meaning.  This text should show what 
a printed text will look like at this place.  If you read this text, 
you will get no information.  Really?  Is there no information?  Is there 
a difference between this text and some nonsense like not at all!  A 
blind text like this gives you information about the selected font, how 
the letters are written and an impression of the look.  This text should
contain all letters of the alphabet and it should be written in of the
original language.There is no need for special content, but the length of
words should match the language.

Hello, here is some text without a meaning.  This text should show what 
a printed text will look like at this place.  If you read this text, 
you will get no information.  Really?  Is there no information?  Is there 
a difference between this text and some nonsense like not at all!  A 
blind text like this gives you information about the selected font, how 
the letters are written and an impression of the look.  This text should
contain all letters of the alphabet and it should be written in of the
original language.There is no need for special content, but the length of
words should match the language.

Hello, here is some text without a meaning.  This text should show what 
a printed text will look like at this place.  If you read this text, 
you will get no information.  Really?  Is there no information?  Is there 
a difference between this text and some nonsense like not at all!  A 
blind text like this gives you information about the selected font, how 
the letters are written and an impression of the look.  This text should
contain all letters of the alphabet and it should be written in of the
original language.There is no need for special content, but the length of
words should match the language.

Hello, here is some text without a meaning.  This text should show what 
a printed text will look like at this place.  If you read this text, 
you will get no information.  Really?  Is there no information?  Is there 
a difference between this text and some nonsense like not at all!  A 
blind text like this gives you information about the selected font, how 
the letters are written and an impression of the look.  This text should
contain all letters of the alphabet and it should be written in of the
original language.There is no need for special content, but the length of
words should match the language.

Hello, here is some text without a meaning.  This text should show what 
a printed text will look like at this place.  If you read this text, 
you will get no information.  Really?  Is there no information?  Is there 
a difference between this text and some nonsense like not at all!  A 
blind text like this gives you information about the selected font, how 
the letters are written and an impression of the look.  This text should
contain all letters of the alphabet and it should be written in of the
original language.There is no need for special content, but the length of
words should match the language.

Hello, here is some text without a meaning.  This text should show what 
a printed text will look like at this place.  If you read this text, 
you will get no information.  Really?  Is there no information?  Is there 
a difference between this text and some nonsense like not at all!  A 
blind text like this gives you information about the selected font, how 
the letters are written and an impression of the look.  This text should
contain all letters of the alphabet and it should be written in of the
original language.There is no need for special content, but the length of
words should match the language.

Hello, here is some text without a meaning.  This text should show what 
a printed text will look like at this place.  If you read this text, 
you will get no information.  Really?  Is there no information?  Is there 
a difference between this text and some nonsense like not at all!  A 
blind text like this gives you information about the selected font, how 
the letters are written and an impression of the look.  This text should
contain all letters of the alphabet and it should be written in of the
original language.There is no need for special content, but the length of
words should match the language.

Hello, here is some text without a meaning.  This text should show what 
a printed text will look like at this place.  If you read this text, 
you will get no information.  Really?  Is there no information?  Is there 
a difference between this text and some nonsense like not at all!  A 
blind text like this gives you information about the selected font, how 
the letters are written and an impression of the look.  This text should
contain all letters of the alphabet and it should be written in of the
original language.There is no need for special content, but the length of
words should match the language.

Hello, here is some text without a meaning.  This text should show what 
a printed text will look like at this place.  If you read this text, 
you will get no information.  Really?  Is there no information?  Is there 
a difference between this text and some nonsense like not at all!  A 
blind text like this gives you information about the selected font, how 
the letters are written and an impression of the look.  This text should
contain all letters of the alphabet and it should be written in of the
original language.There is no need for special content, but the length of
words should match the language.

Hello, here is some text without a meaning.  This text should show what 
a printed text will look like at this place.  If you read this text, 
you will get no information.  Really?  Is there no information?  Is there 
a difference between this text and some nonsense like not at all!  A 
blind text like this gives you information about the selected font, how 
the letters are written and an impression of the look.  

\begin{thebibliography}{}

\bibitem{01} Blankenship, B. (1998). Baker roll 1924: Eastern Band of Cherokee Indians of North Carolina. Cherokee, NC: Cherokee Roots.

\bibitem{02} Kempe, C. H., \& Helfer, R. E. (1980). The battered child (5th ed.). Chicago, IL: University of Chicago Press.

\bibitem{03} World Bank (2004). Gender and development in the Middle East and North Africa: women in the public sphere. Washington, DC: Author.

\bibitem{04} Duncan, G. J., \& Brooks-Gunn, J. (Eds.). (1997). Consequences of growing up poor. New York, NY: Russell Sage Foundation.

\bibitem{05} Ickes, W. (Ed.). (1998). Empathic accuracy. New York, NY: Guilford Press.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic: Don't leave the mandatory argument of the `thebibliography` environment blank. Instead, specify a single-digit number (say, `9`) if the bibliography has fewer than 10 entries, a two-digit number (say, `99`) if the bibliography has more than 9 but fewer than 100 entries, etc.

Comment: Maximizing (or, minimizing, as the case may be) your objective function -- "control automatically the minimum number of lines(5 lines) in last page" of the document -- can not be done in general. The page layout problem does feature a very large number of potentially free parameters. The key word, though, is "potentially": The paper size, the height and width of the text block, the text and math font in use, the font size, the distance between lines of text, the average inter-word distance, and many other parameters may be determined by your publisher -- and thus may not yours to fiddle with.

Comment: Without claim that this a solution, nor that  this will help in any situation, consider allow some paragraph glue. For example, with  `\parskip 1sp plus 12ex minus 1sp`  in the preamble will be make very hard break the references at any point, but at the cost of a big gap at the end of normal text, whilst using the parskip package defaults, or some  like `\parskip 1ex plus 3ex  minus .9ex` will avoid that last gap (at the cost of allow some spaces between paragraphs) but allow a orphan reference in some situations, but probably the result will be better in many cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can test if the end of the second item is near of the end of page, and  break the page if this is true:

```
\ifdim\pagetotal > 460pt  \newpage \fi
```

This generally will work as expected with less or more text, but if you add exactly only 12-14 lines,  `\pagetotal` will be about 530pt or so (that is,  near of `\pagegoal` of 550pt). Then LaTeX could decide that there a optimal break between 1st and 2nd references **without reset  before `\pagetotal` to 0.0pt**.

I don't know now how to solve this correctly, but a poor man solution for this MWE could be a nested conditional to make the page break when the third item is near (but not very near) of the `\pagegoal`:

```
\ifdim \dimexpr\pagetotal+7\baselineskip  > \pagegoal  
   \ifdim \dimexpr\pagetotal+2\baselineskip  > \pagegoal
      \else \newpage 
   \fi
\fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us avoid the aesthetic aspect of tables and assume you want to scale an image to fit the rest of the page.

The `2\lineskip` is a guess on my part.  Removing it makes the image too large, but without the `\vfill` there is a small gap below the image.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]

\vfill{\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height={\dimexpr \pagegoal-\pagetotal-2\lineskip}, 
  keepaspectratio]{example-image}
\par}

\end{document}
```