# Avoid pagebreaks inside paragraph using while obeylines

Tags: page-breaking, paragraphs

Is there a way to stop pagebreaks inside paragraphs in a document with `\obeylines`? I have found this question: [How to avoid page-breaks inside paragraphs?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21983/how-to-avoid-page-breaks-inside-paragraphs), but none of the solutions suggested there seem to work with `\obeylines`. An alternative for `\obeylines` would also help, but I need a global command, not `\\` after every line of text. (I am making a songbook where every line has a hard linebreak, so `\\` would be very impractical)

Here is an example of what I tried:

```
\documentclass[a6paper]{article}

\usepackage[margin=100pt]{geometry}
%\usepackage[defaultlines=100]{nowidow}

\widowpenalties 1 10000
\raggedbottom

%\clubpenalties 1 10000

%\interlinepenalty 10000

\begin{document}

\obeylines

TITLE
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
~\par
bar
bar
bar
bar
bar
bar
bar
bar
\end{document}
```

As is, the bars are split between the two pages of the document. When I tried substituting `\obeylines` with a `\\` on every line, the `\widowpenalties` command worked, but with `\obeylines` it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A page break is normally allowed after `\par`, which is what `\obeylines` issues.

You can use the (new) hook mechanism:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a6paper,margin=100pt]{geometry}

\newcommand{\normalpar}{\par\allowbreak}

\begin{document}

\obeylines\AddToHook{para/after}[obey]{\nobreak}

TITLE
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
~\normalpar
bar
bar
bar
bar
bar
bar
bar
bar

\RemoveFromHook{para/after}[obey]

\clearpage

\obeylines

TITLE
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
~\par
bar
bar
bar
bar
bar
bar
bar
bar

\end{document}
```

The second example shows that `\par` regains its standard properties.

[image]

Better define an environment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a6paper,margin=100pt]{geometry}

\newenvironment{obeynobreak}
 {%
  \par % ensure vertical mode
  \AddToHook{para/after}[obey]{\nobreak}
  \obeylines
 }
 {\RemoveFromHook{para/after}[obey]}
\newcommand{\normalpar}{\par\allowbreak}

\begin{document}

\begin{obeynobreak}
TITLE
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
~\normalpar
bar
bar
bar
bar
bar
bar
bar
bar
\end{obeynobreak}

\clearpage

\obeylines

TITLE
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
~\par
bar
bar
bar
bar
bar
bar
bar
bar

\end{document}
```

Comment: For some reason, I get an `undefined control sequence` error on AddToHook, not really sure why; you mentioned it is a new thing?

Comment: @aky-her You need an up-to-date (at least 2021) version of LaTeX.