# Best way to avoid page break just after epigraph

Tags: vertical-alignment, page-breaking, epigraphs

What is the best way to avoid a page break just after a `\epigraph` command from [epigraph](https://ctan.org/pkg/epigraph) package? I'm adding epigraphs after section titles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}
\usepackage{epigraph}

\begin{document}

    \section{Aaaa}
    \epigraph{$1+2 \neq 3$}{Matlab}

    \lipsum[1-4]


    \section{Bbbb}
    \epigraph{$1+2 \neq 3$}{Matlab}

    \lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```

I tried with `\penalty1000`, with `\nopagebreak`, and with `\clubpenalties` without success.

I managed to do that with `\needspace` like in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/456879/173645), adding to the preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{needspace}
\preto\section{\needspace{7\baselineskip}}
```

Is this a good way? Is there a better one?

Comment: I just realized that even in the first page of epigraph package manual, there's a page break just after a section and an epigraph...

Answer (score 1):

From an old answer of mine that is [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/396216/120578):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}
\usepackage{epigraph}


\newsavebox{\mybottombox} % Box to save the text of the command 
\newlength{\mybottomlength} % The length of our text inside the command
\newlength{\availafter} 
% Optional argument is the minimum length after the nobottom text for not pagebreak. Change it to your needs
\newcommand{\nobottom}[2][60pt]{\savebox{\mybottombox}{\vbox{#2}}\setlength{\mybottomlength}{\ht\mybottombox}%
\setlength{\availafter}{\dimexpr\textheight-\mybottomlength-\pagetotal\relax}\ifdim\availafter<#1%
\pagebreak\noindent\usebox{\mybottombox}%
\else%
\noindent\usebox{\mybottombox}%
\fi%
}%
\begin{document}

    \section{Aaaa}
    \epigraph{$1+2 \neq 3$}{Matlab}

    \lipsum[1-4]


    \section{Bbbb}
    \nobottom{\epigraph{$1+2 \neq 3$}{Matlab}}

    \lipsum[1-4]

    \nobottom[90pt]{\section{Cccc}}
    \epigraph{$1+2 \neq 3$}{Matlab}

    \lipsum[1-4]

\nobottom[90pt]{\section{Dddd}
\epigraph{$1+2 \neq 3$}{Matlab}}

\lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```

I gave a second example of usage that included the `\section` command inside my `\nobottom` in case you wish to use it like this (preferable for me), but added a third example to with both `\section` and `\epigraph` commands inside my command.