# Use verse environment in footnote

Tags: spacing, footnotes, verse

When a verse environment is put in a footnote, it starts a new line, leaving a blank line at the top. How can I start the verse in the first line?

A MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\ldots\ the opening lines of Vergil's Aeneid.\footnote{
\begin{verse}
Arma virumque cano, Troiae qui primus ab oris\\
Italiam, fato profugus, Laviniaque venit\\
litora, multum ille et terris iactatus et alto\\
vi superum saevae memorem Iunonis ob iram;\\
multa quoque et bello passus, dum conderet urbem, \\
inferretque deos Latio, genus unde Latinum,\\
Albanique patres, atque altae moenia Romae.
\end{verse}
}
More text \ldots
\end{document}
```

[image: verse]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`verse` is a list which inserts `topsep` at the start. That, together a `\baselineskip` corrects the vertical placement:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\ldots\ the opening lines of Vergil's Aeneid.\footnote{%
\begin{verse}
  \vspace{-\dimexpr\baselineskip+\topsep}
  Arma virumque cano, Troiae qui primus ab oris\\
  Italiam, fato profugus, Laviniaque venit\\
  litora, multum ille et terris iactatus et alto\\
  vi superum saevae memorem Iunonis ob iram;\\
  multa quoque et bello passus, dum conderet urbem, \\
  inferretque deos Latio, genus unde Latinum,\\
  Albanique patres, atque altae moenia Romae.
\end{verse}
}
More text \ldots
\end{document}
```

Comment: @noir: If you use `\topsep`, then yes. That is, don't use a fixed "guess" for `\topsep`, as it may change depending on where the list is issued. Also, using [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) might ease your spacing needs since it provides a `topsep` key-value option.

Comment: you might want to mention that the use of `\dimexpr` requires `etoolbox`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: You mean e-TeX?

Comment: i guess maybe `\dimexpr` *is* in e-tex; i've just not had to use it since e-tex became the default, so looked for it and found it in `etoolbox.sty`.  glad to be set straight.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: See [What are benefits of e-TeX for LaTeX users?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2114/5764)

Comment: thanks, @werner, i really should follow my own usual advice to "read the documentation".